# The Uniqueness Part of the Smooth-Manifold-Chart-Lemma in John M. Lee's: Question on an answer.

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, smooth-manifolds

I was reading [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928455/the-uniqueness-part-of-the-smooth-manifold-chart-lemma-in-john-m-lees-introduc), but unfortunately I don't understand the following statement made in the following answer given by Amitai Yuval:

"About the topology: Every $(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)$ needs to be a chart, meaning that $\varphi_\alpha$ is a homeomorphism on its image, so for every subset $V\subset U_\alpha$, $V$ is open if and only if $\varphi_\alpha(V)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is open. Since the $U_\alpha$s cover $M$, it means that the collection of open subsets of elements in $\{\varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha)\}$ induces a basis of a topology on $M$, thus the topology is indeed unique."

Denote with $\mathcal{T}_\mathcal{B}$ the topology induced by $\mathcal{B}$ e we suppose that for all $\alpha$, the pair $(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)$ are chart for $M$, then on $M$ exists a topology $\mathcal{T}$ such that $U_\alpha\in\mathcal{T}$ and $\varphi_\alpha\colon U_\alpha\to\varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha)$ is an homeomorphism.

**Claim**: $\mathcal{T}_\mathcal{B}=\mathcal{T}.$

First, for each charts we denote with $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}_{U\alpha}}$ the topology induced by $\mathcal{T}_\mathcal{B}$ on $U_\alpha$, and with $\mathcal{T}_{U_\alpha}$ the topology induce by $\mathcal{T}$ on $U_\alpha$.

Let $A\in\mathcal{T}_\mathcal{B}$, since $U_\alpha\in\mathcal{T}_B$ for all $\alpha$, $A\cap U_\alpha\in\mathcal{T}_\mathcal{B}$, then $A\cap\ U_\alpha=(A\cap U_\alpha)\cap U_\alpha\in\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}_{U_\alpha}}.$

Since $\varphi_\alpha\colon (U_\alpha,\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}_{U_\alpha}})\to\varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha)$ is an homeomorphism , $\varphi_\alpha(A\cap U_\alpha)\subseteq\varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha)$ is open. On the other hand, also

$\varphi_\alpha\colon (U_\alpha,\mathcal{T}_{U_\alpha})\to\varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha)$ is an homeomorphism, then we have that $$\varphi_\alpha^{-1}(\varphi_\alpha(A\cap U_\alpha))=A\cap U_\alpha\in\mathcal{T}_{U_\alpha}\subseteq\mathcal{T}.$$

Since $$A=\bigcup_\alpha (A\cap U_\alpha)\Rightarrow A\in\mathcal{T}.$$

The above shows that $\mathcal{T}_{\mathcal{B}}\subseteq\mathcal{T}.$ In the same way the vice versa can be shown.

It's correct?

> **Question.** What is explicitly meant in this answer, in which we want to show the uniqueness of the topology that satisfies the hypothesis of the lemma?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What "each $(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)$ needs to be a chart" means is "the topology on $M$ needs to be such that, for any $\alpha$, a subset $V \subseteq U_\alpha$ is open if and only if $\varphi_\alpha(V)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$". The only point that Amitai Yuval was making is that "for any $\alpha$, a subset $V \subseteq U_\alpha$ is open if and only if $\varphi_\alpha(V)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$" uniquely determines a topology on $M$, namely, the topology in which a subset $V$ of $M$ is open if and only if $\varphi_\alpha(V\cap U_\alpha)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for each $\alpha$.

Side remark: you should have commented this question on his answer rather than made it a new question on its own.

Comment: @mathworker21Thanks for your answer. But I don't understand why the two topologies are the same. We have a first topology induced by the base $\mathcal{B}$, then we suppose that the pairs $(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)$ are charts, then necessarily $U_\alpha$ is open in $M$ (compared to which topology?) and $\varphi_\alpha\colon U_\alpha\to \varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha)$ is an homeomorphism. How can we say that the two topologies are the same?

Comment: @JackJ. what two topologies are there? The charts impose a necessary condition for a topology on , namely that, for any $\alpha$, a subset $V \subseteq U_\alpha$ is open in $M$ iff $\varphi_\alpha(V)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is just a condition that needs to be satisfied. The point is that the topology induced by the base $\mathcal{B}$ is the only topology satisfying this condition.

Comment: @mothworker21I modified my question, could you check if i got it right?

Comment: @JackJ. looks correct to me!